# Как получить количество записей пользователя группы с помощью VK API

Tags: php, vkontakte-api

Есть группа в контакте, в ней около 20К записей. Нужно получить общее количество записей от одного пользователя с помощью API. Из документации я понял что такого метода нет, но можно сделать таким образом: при добавлении новой записи на стену группы, просто записывать данные автора и кол-во его записей в базу, а в последующем просто увеличивать счетчик. Но это не совсем оптимальный способ. Возможно есть более простые решения, подскажите!?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если под "записями" подразумеваются посты (не комментарии!) то с помощью метода wall.get можно брать по 100 постов со стены, а если использовать execute то в одном запросе можно забирать 25*100=2500 постов, соответственно 20К постов в группе это меньше 10 запросов. Алгоритм возможен следующий - первый раз снимаем все посты и записываем в БД пары пост/автор и потом с некой периодичностью снимаем 2500 последний постов. Ну и далее простейший подсчет постов автора в БД.